# Elasticsearch-Spark serialization not working with inner classes

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

Elasticsearch/Spark serialization does not appear to play well with nested types.

For example:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
   private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
   // getters and setters

   public static class Bar implements Serializable {
   }
}

List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
foos.add( new Foo());
// Note: Foo object does not contain nested Bar instances

SparkConf sc = new SparkConf(); //
sc.setMaster("local");
sc.setAppName("spark.app.name");
sc.set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName()); 
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
JavaRDD javaRDD = jsc.parallelize(ImmutableList.copyOf(foos));
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, INDEX_NAME+"/"+TYPE_NAME);
```

The above code above works, and documents of type `Foo` will be indexed within Elasticsearch.

The issue arises when the `bars` list in a `Foo` object is not empty, for instance:

```
Foo = new Foo();
Bar = new Foo.Bar();
foo.getBars().add(bar);
```

Then, when indexing to Elasticsearch, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.EsHadoopSerializationException: 
Cannot handle type [Bar] within type [class Foo], instance [Bar ...]] 
within instance [Foo@1cf628a] 
using writer [org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueWriter@4e635d]
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.builder.ContentBuilder.value(ContentBuilder.java:63)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.doWriteObject(TemplatedBulk.java:71)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.write(TemplatedBulk.java:58)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:148)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:47)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:68)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

These are the relevant Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
   <artifactId>elastic4s_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
   <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop-cascading</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
   <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the correct way to index when using nested types with ElasticSearch and Spark?

Thanks

Comment: you need to serialize your Foo and Bar objects!

Comment: implements Serializable?

Comment: In Java yes, since it's an interface.

Comment: Added 'implements Serializable' to both Foo and Bar classes, but still get the same exception: Cannot handle type [Bar] within type [class Foo], instance [Bar ...]] 
within instance [Foo@1cf628a] 
using writer [org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueWriter@4e635d]

Comment: Is the problem described is related to the following issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/327

Comment: that issue is fixed a while ago!

Comment: I see that the issue exists even if there is only one Bar object referenced in Foo: private Bar bar; (instead of private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();). Still the same org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueWriter exception.

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be to build a json from the object you're trying to save, using for example [Json4s](http://json4s.org/).
In this case your "JavaEsSpark" RDD would be a RDD of strings.
Then you simply have to call

`JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs...`

instead of

`JavaEsSpark.saveToEs...`

This workaround helped me save countless hours trying to figure out a way to Serialize nested maps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ScalaValueWriter & JdkValueWriter code we can see that only certain types are directly supported. Most likely the inner class is not a JavaBean or other supported type.

Comment: Thanks Holden, but what is the solution then? Even if Bar is not an inner class but a regular class, it cannot be added as a member of Foo. The same exception is thrown. In other words, how can I define Bar so it can be added to Foo?

Comment: Make it a Java bean :)

Comment: Bar is a Javabean already (public no-args constructor, implements Serializable, public getters and setters). That by itself does not allow Foo to contain an instance variable of type Bar. (Foo has String, long, Date etc, ScalaValueWriter has no problem with those).

Answer (score 0):

One day ScalaValueWriter & JdkValueWriter will possibly support user defined types (like `Bar` in our example), other than just Java types like String, int, etc.

In the meantime, there is the following workaround. Instead of having `Foo` expose a List of `Bar` objects, internally transform the List to a `Map<String, Object>` and expose that.

Something like this:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> bars= new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

public List<Map<String, Object>> getBars() {
   return bars;
}

public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
   for (Bar bar: bars){
      this.bars.add(bar.getAsMap());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest working with com.google.gson.Gson;

```
String  foosJson = new Gson().toJson(foos );
```

then ,
    Map map = new HashMap<> ();
 ...
 ...

```
JavaRDD<Map<String,?>> javaRDD= sc.parallelize(ImmutableList.of(map));

JavaEsSpark.saveToEs ( javaRDD, INDEX_NAME+"/"+TYPE_NAME );
```